# How to change bibliography title size in book class

Tags: bibliographies, fontsize, bibliographystyle

I am using the `book` class in overleaf and when using the command `\begin{thebibliography}`, the title BIBLIOGRAPHY printed is far too large.

How would I go about changing this to a 9pt font title without affecting any other titles?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{XXX}%  the default
    foo \\bar baz
\end{thebibliography}

\bgroup%   hold the changes local
\let\Huge\Large
\begin{thebibliography}{XXX}%  smaller heading
foo \\bar baz
\end{thebibliography}
\egroup
    
\end{document}
```